# using $.getJSON my links contains %0A+++++ characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am try to get the values from the selected row and pass them through $.getJSON as parameters. I can get the value, however, when I click on the link strange characters appear before and after the value. The character in the link appears as %OA++++++++++value+++++++%0A.

Here is my code

```
var className='';
var Section='';
$('#listsubject tr').click(function () {
            var th = $(this);
            var td = $(this).find('td');

            $.each(td, function (index, item) {
                if (index == 2) className = item.innerHTML;

            });


 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("getStudentList/","Student")',
                { classname: className
                }, function (data) {
   alert('test');
});
```

Kindly help me. Am stuck here

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

when i try the code

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("getStudentList/","Student")',
                    { classname: className,
                      section:'A'
                    }, function (data) {
       alert('test');
    });
```

in the link the section part shows fine, only problem is with the classname

**UPDATE**

fiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/gordon/vzTDc/2/

Comment: @thecodeparadox sorry i haven't use fiddle :(

Comment: @Gordon -- what he means is visit http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a demonstration of the problem. JSFiddle.net is a site where you can post JS/CSS/HTML code to experiment with and see how it works in controlled environment. Very useful for debugging, and also for showing people what the problem is.

Comment: @Spudley thanks to your suggestion... i now am a big fan of jsfiddle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think its OK now.

```
var className = '',
    Section = '';

// you were trying with $('#listsubject tr'), but first tr has no td
// so click should bind with tr from 2nd
// so correct selector will be $('#listsubject tr:gt(0)')

$('#listsubject tr:gt(0)').click(function() {
    var th = $(this);
    var td = $(this).find('td');
    $.each(td, function(index, item) {

        // As you have 2 td with in each row, so the index will be 0 and 1
        // not 2 and 3

        if (index == 0) {
            className = $.trim($(item).text()); // $.trim() will remove spaces
        }
        if (index == 1) {
            Section = $.trim($(item).text());
        }
    });
    console.log('ClassName: ' + className + ', Section: ' + Section);
    $.getJSON('StudentMarks/getSubjectGrading', {
        classname: className,
        section: Section
    }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/vzTDc/12/)**

Comment: $(item).html(); returns null while $(item).text(); returns blank

Comment: when i use alert(className) it shows the correct value. Then y does the extra character appear in the link using $.getJSON ? WHen using .text or .html it shows as undefined

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it still shows the same characters (%0A++++++ )

Comment: what does this %0A++++ means in a link anyway?

Comment: @Gordon until you make a fiddle or post your markup its not possible to take any further step

Comment: when using $(item).html, it prints the correct value when using alert(className). however, when in the link that's when the problem starts